# Numeric problems in PHP (max possible value for a 64 unsigned integer)

Tags: php

This is the example code I'm running.

```
<?php

   //$maxval = (2**64)-1;
   $maxval = (2**64);
   $maxval = $maxval-10000;
 
   echo number_format($maxval,0,".","") . "\n";
   echo "18446744073709551615\n";
 
 
?>
```

The code if for checking a number that will come as a string and I need to make sure it is an unsigned 64 bit integer. So once I check that the string is composed ONLY of numbers I need to make sure that the range is correct.

But I'm getting some weird behaviour.

This line (2**64)-1; printed 18446744073709551616. It seemed it ignored the -1. So I started changing -1 to -10, -100, -1000 and they all printed the same value. It only changed when I changed it to -10000 and this is what it printed:

```
18446744073709541376
18446744073709551615
```

But to my understanding the first line should be

```
18446744073709541615
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer in PHP is a signed integer. There are constants PHP_INT_MIN and PHP_INT_MAX for the smallest and largest value.

```
//64 Bit PHP Version !
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);  //int(9223372036854775807) = 2**63-1
```

If the values ​​are greater than the integer range, PHP automatically converts to float. Float, however, is far less precise than 63 bits. This is where the inaccuracies come from.

The [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.bc.php) functions can be used to calculate with almost any precision. This code is for checking a number that will come as a string and is an unsigned 64 bit integer.

```
$val = "18446744073709551614";

$maxUnsign64Bit ="18446744073709551615";
if(ctype_digit($val) AND bccomp($val,$maxUnsign64Bit) !== 1){
  echo 'is a 64 Bit number';
};
```